# How to add {riseOnHover: true} to Leaflet code

Tags: leaflet

I want to force marker labels to top using  {riseOnHover: true}. I can't seem to implement this with my existing code, which utilizes Omivore to handle csv to marker.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwc3RlciIsImEiOiI3RmFfME5ZIn0.73sdzUFNqSsGQzjlsnimaA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '1000-days.e2eb0e4z')
.setView([38, -95], 4);

omnivore.csv('./Aprils_World_Map.csv',)

.on('ready', function(layer) {

    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.country === 'Italy') {

            marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
               'marker-symbol': 'star',
                'marker-color': '#EF5528',
                'marker-size': 'small',
            }));
        } else {
            marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
           'marker-symbol': 'star',
           'marker-color': '#EF5528',
            'marker-size': 'small'
            }));
        }

        marker.bindLabel(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.city + ', ' +
            marker.toGeoJSON().properties.country);

    }); 
})

.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting options like that

```
this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
   L.setOptions(marker, {riseOnHover: true});
});
```

Comment: in your eachLayer callback